# Is there a website which explains the recent Windows updates?

Tags: windows-update, documentation

When windows informs me that there are new updates, I open the Windows Update dialog box. The new updates are listed as code names like `KBxxxxxxx`. The right panel contains the same copy/pasted boring explanation text for each update. When I click on the `More information` link on that dialog box, it goes to the page of the update: `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/xxxxxxx`. On that page, purpose of the update is rarely explained. Most of the time, the thing that has been fixed or the new feature that comes with the update is not specified. It is like Microsoft is trying hard to hide what the updates are for.

I want to know what will change on my computer when I install an update. However, I don't have time and endurance to find the information on the official website of Microsoft. I know I can find the details somewhere in the depths of `microsoft.com` if I try hard enough, but I would like to know a simpler way of this. Is there a blog, portal, forum or dedicated website which analyzes and clearly explains contents of each update?

Comment: [Microsoft Technical Security Notifications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/dd252948) you can use either their RSS feed or get e-mail notifications, or just come back to the website to see updates.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft releases Windows Updates on the second Tuesday of every month. You can receive advance notification of the contents of these updates by subscribing to Microsoft Security Bulletin Summaries at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/gg309152.aspx

Here are the updates from today (the second Tuesday of November): https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms14-nov

As far as "contents" of the updates are concerned, you won't typically see a list of changed files, registry keys, data stores, etc...Especially with security updates. As an administrator, you see a critical update is required for X application and enough information will typically be provided to help you assess the risk of installing the update. As long as you understand how X application works with your system.

There is also terminology to be aware of to help understand the contents of an update. You can rely on Microsoft's naming conventions to understand whether or not an update will offer new features or a simple bug fix, for example:

> - **Critical update**: A widely released fix for a specific problem that addresses a critical, non-security-related bug.
> - **Definition update:** A widely released and frequent software update that contains additions to a product’s definition database. Definition databases are often used to detect objects that 
>     have specific attributes, such as malicious code, phishing websites, or junk mail.
> - **Driver:** Definition: Software that controls the input and output of a device.
> - **Feature pack:** Definition: New product functionality that is first distributed outside the context of a product release and that is typically included in the next full product release.
> - **Security update** Definition: A widely released fix for a product-specific, security-related vulnerability. Security vulnerabilities are rated by their severity. The severity rating is indicated in the Microsoft security bulletin as critical, important, moderate, or low.
> - **Service pack:** Definition: A tested, cumulative set of all hotfixes, security updates, critical updates, and updates. Additionally, service packs may contain additional fixes for problems that are found internally since the release of the product. Service packs my also contain a limited number of customer-requested design changes or features.
> - **Tool** Definition: A utility or feature that helps complete a task or set of tasks.
> - **Update** Definition: A widely released fix for a specific problem. An update addresses a noncritical, non-security-related bug.
> - **Update rollup** Definition: A tested, cumulative set of hotfixes, security updates, critical updates, and updates that are packaged together for easy deployment. A rollup generally targets a specific area, such as security, or a component of a product, such as Internet Information Services (IIS).